# Free Web Based Electronic Laboratory Notebook (ELN) with Sufficient Storage and DOI assignment and legal measures

Tags: note-taking, web-services

Most of these provide limited free storage.
[Wiki of ELNs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ELN_software_packages)

I was shocked by the space of http://www.labarchives.com/professional-edition/ (25MB) and sciNote does not provide legal certification or DOI, etc.
Is there any free web based electronic laboratory notebook with sufficient storage (GBs) and DOI assignment and other needed legal measures in order to be equivalent or more ensured as a research result as a normal paper lab note? (21CFR 11 is preferable but doi is more important, and covers up for 21CFR 11)
If not doi, static links that will last at least 5 years should be present for all notes. 
P.S>I study bioinformatics, neuroinformatics, computer science, molecular biology.

Comment: Great question. You mentioned that you are a student, so maybe you could ask your professors or lab technicians what do they have in mind? After all, you are probably is looking for a solution that also allows collaboration and sharing data with these people.

Comment: Well my instructor actually still uses a paper lab notebook and he is also looking for a stable and legal ELN that will be accepted by other professors who don't use ELNs.